# Is there a way in which taskbar can be removed from bottom of the screen in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, gaming

I have spent my whole day trying to figure out the way in which taskbar can be hidden from the screen, its very annoying.

The problem started when I was playing a game and there I pressed win + G (to screen record the game) and since then the taskbar is taskbar is affixed at bottom.

I have used this link already but it didn't help. I have also tried applying all answers on superuser regarding this but didn't help.

I guess its got some problem with screen recording of the game.

Its annoying me to an extent that if I were financially able I would have purchased a new laptop today itself.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/reset-taskbar-to-default-settings-on-windows-10/2ef0bf7d-1b7c-4115-ab8a-a36e75b34f2a

[See taskbar at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZTh2.png)

Comment: Have you reset your computer...? Is your Taskbar automatically hidden in the taskbar settings?

Comment: @NatsuKage earlier also it wasn't hidden but it never appeared at the bottom while using chrome or any other app.

Comment: You're probably using an old version of windows. But try hiding it again using the taskbar settings. Read this as well: https://www.guidingtech.com/windows-10-taskbar-not-hiding-in-fullscreen-8-ways-to-solve-it/

Comment: @NatsuKage I'm sorry to disappoint you but I'm not using old version of Windows and I have spent my whole day and have already exhausted the 8 methods mentioned in your link, nothing worked.

Comment: By old version: what is your Windows 10 version? I've had this issue a lot of Win10 1511. To tell this right click on the windows Icon, select System -> Windows Specifications

Comment: @NatsuKage Windows 10 Pro Version1909.

Comment: It must be another Windows bug then.

Comment: Your picture is normal. What do you want.

Comment: @Mark See the taskbar at the bottom,while browsing chrome which generally is not visible while using other apps.

Comment: @Moab Do you have any clue what it can be and how it can be corrected?

Comment: Set the properties not "Automatically hide taskbar in Desktop mode" in Taskbar settings.

Comment: @Mark its already set.

Comment: It looks to me you are in Tablet mode. Click the notification sidebar and turn off.

Comment: @Mark No I'm in Desktop Mode